# Facebook login web javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, email

Tengo un problema y llevo un par de días sin encontrar solución, quiero poner el botón de login de facebook en mi web y he logrado obtener el email pero solo en fase de desarrollo cuando la pongo la aplicación en real ya no me captura el email, solo obtiene el email de las  cuentas developer y necesito poder pillar el email para poder hacer un registro del usuario cuando se logue por primera vez con su cuenta de facebook, cualquier ayuda es bien recibida, gracias!

```
    function statusChangeCallback(response)
    {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);

        if (response.status === 'connected')
        {
            testAPI();
        }
        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized')
        {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Inicia sesión';
        }
        else
        {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Inicia sesión';
        }
    }

    function checkLoginState()
    {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
            // the session
            xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version    : 'v2.5' // use version 2.5
        });
    };

    function login_fb()
    {
        FB.login(function(response){  
            validarUsuario();  
        }, {scope: 'public_profile, email'});  
    }

    function validarUsuario()
    {  
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {  
            if(response.status == 'connected') {
                testAPI();
            } else if(response.status == 'not_authorized') {  
                alert('Debes autorizar la app!');  
            } else {  
                alert('Debes ingresar a tu cuenta de Facebook!');  
            }  
        });  
    }

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Bienvenido ');
        FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,first_name,last_name', function(response) {
            console.log('Este es el email: ' + response.email);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo sigues este documento en tu implementacion

[Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

imagino que el usario con el cual te autenticas la primera vez quede en cache por eso toma siempre la misma autenticacion

Que pasa si implementas un logout

[Facebook Javascript SDK: Basic Login and Logout example](https://gist.github.com/heldrida/6232556)

```
    function logout() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          // user is now logged out
        });
    }
```

para que el sitio vuelva a pedirte las credenciales, pero valida que redirecciona al sitio de facebook, ingresas las credenciales de la persona y redirecciona a tu sitio.

En tu implementación veo el login, pero no el logout por eso si el usuario esta en cache usa siempre sus credenciales dando por buena la autenticacion, con un logout fuerzas a cambiar de usuario.

**>>a loguear se abre la venta de autorización y veo los permisos que solicita (email y perfil publico) acepto, pero no me devuelve el email pero si abro facebook aparezco logueado**

Analizando la api

[Graph API Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api)

puedo ver que los parametros no los asignas de forma correcta, intenta usando algo como ser

```
FB.api('/me', 'get', { access_token: token, fields: 'id,name,mail' },  function(response) {
       console.log(response);
 });
```

Nota: puede intentar pasandole o no el token

Comment: Hola Leandro, es cierto que no tengo el logout pero el error no va por ese lado ya que he intentado acceder desde otro pc y no me obtiene el email de una cuenta no developer. a lo mejor puede ser la configuración de la app en facebook¿?

Comment: cuando defines el proyecto dentro del la config de facebook le indicas que datos va a requerir acceder ? valida el punto 11 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register#development-mode quizas debas tengas que inhabilitar esa opcion para acceder a los datos del usuario que se autentica

Comment: En principio ya no lo tengo como desarrollo y lo unico que necesito es el email y nombre,

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5wHj4NL0iV-M3VURlhpZUpCRkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Es un poco raro la verdad, porque cuando le doy a loguear se abre la venta de autorización y veo los permisos que solicita (email y perfil publico) acepto, pero no me devuelve el email pero si abro facebook aparezco logueado......

Comment: @luisinho intenta usa la api de FB.api() asignando los parametro como se menciona en la doc de la api

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5wHj4NL0iV-eXp0X0h6bmFkMkU/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5wHj4NL0iV-RmZWcWNGNXdTMG8/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5wHj4NL0iV-UkJ6anF2bW9iMlE/view?usp=sharing

he probado con el ejemplo de facebook y con las modificaciones que me has ido diciendo pero sigue sin funciona :'(   ..esto pareciera que fuera tema de configuración pero no sé, en configuración -> advanced hay que modificar algo¿?, gracias!!!! :)

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Mi recomendación es que uses esta herramienta [Auth0](https://auth0.com)